# Get events of microphone inside a iframe - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get the events of microphone inside a iframe using JavaScript?
In the beginning, I have checked the postMessage() method that enables communication from iframe to parent but somehow that's not working.

```
<iframe class="iframe-home" id="iframe" allow="camera;microphone;fullscreen;autoplay;display-capture" width="auto" height="500" scrolling="yes" src="{URL}&mute=mic&events=true">

 const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
                
    window.addEventListener("message", ({ data, source })=> {
        console.log(source,iframe.contentWindow);
        if (source === iframe.contentWindow) {
            const { type, event, ...extra } = data;
            console.log(type, event,extra);
        }
    });  

    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(
        {
            type: "conference",
            action: "mute",
        },
        "*"
    );
```

Then I tried to listen events in the current window by using [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) API, but first it initialises the microphone. Not able to get the current microphone events & state present inside the iframe.

```
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(stream => {
            console.log('started');                                      
        }).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: postMessage will only work when the iframe content is configured to respond to message events.  See [postMessage - security concerns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#security_concerns)

Comment: I'm using a third party API and configuration of iframe are present to respond to message events as per their documentation. So I followed the same but no results. As you can see I have used *mute* event based on the documentation.